# Usage of Logitech mouse (M705) buttons for navigation in browser on a mac

Tags: mac, google-chrome, logitech-mouse

I am using a Mac. Is there a way of enabling the many buttons/ functional elements (e.g. scroll wheel) of my Logitech mouse (M705) in order to control navigating through my browser (preferably Chrome)? I am looking for functions like:

- Going backward and forward between different web pages.
- Opening pages in new tab
- etc. etc.

Any extensions, drivers, scripts? Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [MMB](https://superuser.com/users/259682/mmb) mentioned, you need the [Logitech Control Center](http://support.logitech.com/en_us/product/marathon-mouse-m705). But to have it allow you to open a new tab with a wheel click, you need to get a little creative with that.

After it's installed:

1. System Preferences > Logitech Control Center
2. Configure the mouse you want
3. Change the wheel click to "Advanced Click"
4. In the settings for that use the "click" type and then add the ⌘ modifier

⌘ + click in Chrome is another way to open a new tab in Chrome so this combines all that into the mouse click.

As for going forwards and backwards, that should just be available with the standard "Forward" and "Back" options, which should be the default set on the thumb buttons.

Comment: Unfortunately this won't let you wheel click on a tab at the top to close it. The big one here is being able to open in new tab with just a click.

Answer (score 0):

Download the drivers for it, which appears to be called [Logitech Control Center](http://support.logitech.com/en_us/product/marathon-mouse-m705).

Comment: Yes I did, but it is not allowing me to make any "browser-related" settings... right?

Comment: Ah.  I saw "scroll wheel" and assumed it wasn't working, which it should be by default as that's an OS level function.  As for more specific browser-related extensions, does LCC allow you to map mouse buttons to keyboard commands?  For Chrome back is command-[ and forward is command-].  For opening pages in a new tab, clicking on the middle-button (scroll-wheel for those mice capable).Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

I've installed the [Logitech Options](https://support.logi.com/hc/en-us/articles/360025297893) and assign my desired keystroke to mouse keys